# Pictures that behave as symbols in textbox (or something like textbox)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, controls, custom-controls

I need to create a control, that behaves like a textbox, but allows you to replace some (or all) of the characters with pictures that behave (select and remove with backspace/delete) as a normal characters.

I tried to create a RichTextBox inherited control, with "CanPaste - Paste" construction, but the images added this way didn't act like the characters, but as the images which can be resized. It's not a correct solution for me.

So, the question is: How can I override "symbol drawing" method? I mean, get actual (x,y) coordinates of drawing character, and draw picture instead of it (or in front of it). Is that possible?

Control should look similar to this picture. (lockers on picture are images, acting like symbols.)
[image: what I want to achieve]

UPD: **Control must be working on systems from XP to 8**, so using UTF-8 lock-style symbol won't be a solution for me. Control shown on the screenshot above works in an application that is running on a Windows XP — though I have no idea which way it was implemented.

Comment: Just use U+1F512:   textBox1.Text = "Locked";

Comment: @HansPassant, I updated the question — the method should work at least on Windows 7 (or better on XP), but all I see - https://pp.vk.me/c314819/v314819396/3cf6/iofGSHKfiMA.jpg.

By the way, this (http://i.stack.imgur.com/b4sjo.png) screenshot was taken from another application works fine on Windows XP - but I have no idea how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

What I would is use a `PasswordBox` with a `FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"` and the `PasswordChar="& # xE14D;"` (remove the spaces). This will render this:
[image]

The complete code: `<PasswordBox Password="Example" Width="100" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" PasswordChar="&#xE14D;" />`

Comment: Windows 8 required.  Might as well use U+1F512 if you have that requirement.

Comment: It's an option. You also stated: "I can't vouch for earlier versions"